# Drawing 4-variable Karnaugh map: concerns related to karnaugh-map package and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, karnaugh

I am not very familiar with both packages, mainly the `karnaugh-map` package. I am trying to make a Karnaugh Map of 4 variables and using two different approaches I could get the results partially in one and partially in another.

Using the `karnaugh-map` package:

```
\begin{karnaugh-map}*[4][4][1][][]      
    \maxterms{0,1,2,3,4,5,6}
    \minterms{7}
    \autoterms[X]  
    \implicant{7}{15}       
    \end{karnaugh-map}
```

[image]

Using tikzpicture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \karnaughmap
    [omitidx,omitbinaries,
    omitnegated=false,
    variables={{Q_1}{Q_0}{Q_3}{Q_2}},
    function=J_3]   
    {00XX 00XX 00XX 01XX} 
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

The final map I want to accomplish is equal to the second map, but has the square of the first map (`\implicant{7}{15}`), using the package you can easily set the groups. But I don't want the binaries presented in the first map. I would like the variables visible as the second map, but the value `0` is not shown and I couldn't draw the square. On the other hand, it has the functions omitidx and omitbinaries.

I am not sure if there's another package or way to accomplish it. Using the `karnaugh-map` package the `\implicant`  function makes it way  easy to drawn the squares and show the groups, but it is harder using tikzpicture.

Answer (score 1):

In the first `scope` is your (second) code with two lines added. The first one is the option `omitzeros=false` which shows the zeros, and the second is a `\draw` command that draws the desired rectangle with tikz. I also show a second `scope` with an additional example.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaughmap}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \begin{scope} % first map
    \karnaughmap
    [omitidx,omitbinaries,
    omitnegated=false,
    omitzeros=false, % to show the zeros
    variables={{Q_1}{Q_0}{Q_3}{Q_2}},
    function=J_3]   
    {00XX 00XX 00XX 01XX}   
    \draw [red, rounded corners] (2.1,1.1) rectangle (2.9,2.9);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(7,0)}] % second map
    \karnaughmap
    [omitidx,omitbinaries,
    omitnegated=false,
    omitzeros=false, % to show the zeros
    variables={{Q_1}{Q_0}{Q_3}{Q_2}},
    function=J_3']   
    {10XX 00XX 00XX 00XX}
    \draw[red, rounded corners] (0.1,0) -- (0.1,0.9) -| (0.9,0);
    \draw[red, rounded corners] (0.1,4) -- (0.1,3.1) -| (0.9,4);
  \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]